# How to print a string value in single line using Perl

Tags: perl, string-concatenation

My problem is simple one...
My perl code is like below...

```
 $todaydate = `date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S`;
 $output_file = "my_data_$todaydate".".csv";
 print "SQL query output file name : $output_file\n";
```

But the Output file name is printing as like below...

```
SQL query output file name : my_data_2017-10-03-062227
.csv
```

If you can observe, the .csv is coming in new line.
I have also tried the below join for string conactantion. but still no luck.

```
$output_file = join "", "my_data_", $todaydate, ".csv";
```

due to this issue, while i am passing the output_file name to a sql query, its creating a file my_data_2017-10-03-062227 without .csv extension.

Any suggestion please...

Comment: `chomp $todaydate`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several reasons why you might not want to use external programs unnecessarily.

- The external program might not be available (or might work differently) on some systems where you want to run your program. You are therefore making your code less portable.
- Starting a new shell and invoking an external program takes longer than just using a Perl feature to achieve the same result.
- The value returned from an external problem will probably have a newline character at the end - and you might forget to remove it.

Getting a date is a task that people commonly want to use an external program for. And I don't understand why, because Perl has pretty good built-in time and date handling. For example, your code can be written like this:

```
use Time::Piece;

$todaydate = localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S');
$output_file = "my_data_$todaydate.csv";
print "SQL query output file name : $output_file\n";
```

[Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) has been included with all versions of Perl since 2007. It changes the behaviour of `localtime()` so it returns an object. And the object has many useful methods - here we use `strftime()`.

If you're stuck with an older version of Perl (pre-5.10) then you can still do this easily without calling an external program.

```
use POSIX 'strftime';

$todaydate = strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S', localtime);
$output_file = "my_data_$todaydate.csv";
print "SQL query output file name : $output_file\n";
```

Comment: This solution apt perfectly. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

use chomp in your `$todaydate` variable.

```
my $todaydate = `date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S`;
chomp $todaydate;
my $output_file = "my_data_$todaydate.csv";
```

Always put `use warnings;` and `use strict;` in top of the program.

Comment: Wow! its worked. I am new to Perl Script. Thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: Or, perhaps, give an alternative answer that doesn't require running an external program!

Answer (score -1):

Its because of new line character at the end of `$todaydate`. Use below to fix it:

```
$todaydate =~ s/\n|\r//g;
```

The above code will remove any occurrence of `\n` or `\r`.

Comment: Isn't that what `chomp()` is for?

Comment: Someone has already given that answer, i just gave an alternative option. Regular expression is really helpful in perl and don't have to hunt for builtin functions if you know how to use them.